# Encouraging Area 51 proposal ads in the side bar

Tags: support, area-51, sidebar

Sometimes there are ads on the side bar for site proposals:

[image]

I want people to see ads for a site proposal that I am interested in. Is there something I have to do to encourage ads for a specific proposal to pop up?

I ask because I don't know how the side bar ads work:

- Are they random?
- I read *[Is it possible to get the Area 51 ads on my site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76778/is-it-possible-to-get-the-area-51-ads-on-my-site)* which I think implies that some mod on the site has to explicitly add one; is my interpretation correct? Does that mean I should start canvassing mods to try to get my proposal in their site's side bar?
- I vaguely remember seeing something on some site somewhere where user-created sidebar ads were posted in a meta thread and somehow that was linked to the rotation of ads displayed on the sidebar. Is that how it works? Does every site have one of these threads and, if so, how do I find it?
- Is it a Stack Exchange-wide pool of ads or is it site-specific?

How do I go from "I really want to spread the word about a site proposal" to "Users see sidebar ads for the proposal"?

Comment: I think that [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261083/how-related-should-a-site-proposal-be-in-order-to-ask-for-a-community-ad) may answer your question. It's not really a dupe, but it addresses just about everything you need.