# How to best leverage the Community Ads feature for maximum contribution?

Tags: discussion, graduating-sites, community-promotion-ads, incentive

The beta community that I moderate may be up for maturation in 2022 -- which would allow for "[Community Ads](https://joomla.meta.stackexchange.com/q/386/12352)".

I am very excited to gain this feature because it represents a real opportunity to extend community reach into pre-existing networks and bring awareness to undiscovered tools and possibilities.

I am wondering, though, is there a way to incentivize more activity in exchange for this generous/free feature so that it can be better leveraged? I don't mean to create a barrier/hurdle, but I don't want it to be "too cheap" either.  Might I institute a slight modification of the qualifying requirements before a user is able to drop a free ad into our community? I am open to abstract, constructive, creative thinking.  For example, might our community ask community members to meet some specific metric of contribution (more than being able to post on meta), before the ad will be "considered for upvoting"?

Relevant links:

- [Appropriate content for community ads](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147312/352329)
- [Define Scope of Community Promotion Ads?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/2821)
- [How do we get Community Promotion Ads on beta sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/248214/352329)

Comment: The minimum number of votes seems like sufficient barrier - is there a reason that's not enough to show community support?

Comment: 5 rep is enough of a barrier to prevent an imbalance of generosity between Stack Exchange and external business/software owners?

Comment: Answers must have a score of at least six to be considered - If your community dislikes the ad - they should downvote the proposed ad so that it does not get that score. Y'all have a lot of control - we don't just make ads for anyone who writes an answer.

Comment: Yes, that would be how I would attempt to enforce a human-imposed requirement (because currently there is only a 5-rep requirement to post). Do I want someone who has invested in my community to be able to benefit from advertising their product, or do I want any drifter with an association bonus to be able to inject their ad into the community? I feel that ads are super powerful features.  I want to prevent a lopsided/parasitic relationship with it.  I also want to incentivize more activity/contribution in my community.

Comment: I'm so very, very confused. The rule requiring a score of six already exists. Nothing needs to change to make that happen. Community ads aren't generally designed to be "Product" ads - they're intended to be links to things that the community would find valuable - things like informational blogs or resources that relate to their subject or events. They're not designed to be for selling a specific product.

Comment: I mean if a user made one post and got one upvote, they could advertise their business for free.  I feel this is not balanced.  Maybe I'd like a minimum of 10 non-negative voted posts in the community to show investment.  More of a "scratch my back, then I'll scratch yours".  Maybe read my first link and tell me if I am misunderstanding the usage of ads?

Comment: It doesn't matter how much participation someone has on the site. It just doesn't. If your community does not upvote that proposed ad so that it has a score of six, it will never exist on your site. Your first link doesn't give y'all ads - you posting a copycat post does not create community ads on your site. You're kinda just wasting everyone's time. [This is the current practice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364556/the-future-of-community-promotion-open-source-and-hot-network-questions-ads) for Community Ads.

Comment: Yes, it was a "practice run" after I realised that betas don't get ads. I also understand that it doesn't **currently** matter about user participation -- I'm entertaining raising the bar for the betterment of the community.